# Where do I start? I have a massive dataset (from web scraping) and want to predict y from 20 variables

Tags: machine-learning, regression

I'm trying to do my best to recreate an algorithm that a company is using by sucking in all of its outputs and adding in some relevant variables (I won't be able to perfectly recreate it as I'm missing inventory data). I'm guessing this is a job for machine learning but I was wondering where I start? Are there specific models I should start with? Software I should use? Courses I should dive into?

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Peter The best way to think of it is trying to recreate the dynamic pricing that an airline would use for flights. the "y" or output, in this example, would be the price.

Comment: it seems work for `Regession`. If you use `Python` then you have module [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/). For visual work you can use [Orange3](https://orange.biolab.si/screenshots/)

Comment: you can also try Neural Network with tensorflow (from Google) - [Basic regression: Predict fuel efficiency](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression). But other big companies should have also tools for Neural Network (Facebook, Amazon, Intel, IBM, Microsoft). Some of tools can be used online - ie. [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are really new to all this, here are some suggestions.

Download and [install R](https://www.r-project.org/) and [RStudio Desktop](https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/).

Look at the book ["Introduction to Statistical Learning"](https://github.com/tpn/pdfs/blob/master/An%20Introduction%20To%20Statistical%20Learning%20with%20Applications%20in%20R%20(ISLR%20Sixth%20Printing).pdf). The book comes with [code examples](http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/code.html) (in R) which are ideal to start learning. For you it will be useful to have a look at Chapter 2 to understand what statistical learning is all about and also to get a good idea of how to use R.

However, what is really relevant for you is Chapter 3 (linear regression) and Chapter 7 (moving beyond linearity).

Now you can get started. Here are some examples how regression can be done in R:

```
# Install a package if needed
# install.packages("ISLR")

# Lead packages
library(ISLR)
library(gam)
library(Metrics)

# Look at data
head(mtcars)
# Look at one variable in our dataframe
summary(mtcars$mpg)

# Make a test/train split
set.seed(123)
smp_size <- floor(0.75 * nrow(mtcars))
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(mtcars)), size = smp_size)
train <- mtcars[train_ind, ]
test <- mtcars[-train_ind, ]

# Linear regression
# Estimate mpg (y) dependent on ...
reg1 = lm(mpg~disp+wt+qsec+hp, data=train)
summary(reg1)

# Regression with polinomials
reg2 = lm(mpg~poly(disp,2)+poly(wt,2)+poly(qsec,2)+poly(hp,2), data=train)
summary(reg2)

# Generalised additive models (regression splines)
reg3 = gam(mpg~s(disp,3)+s(wt,3)+s(qsec,3)+s(hp,3),data=train)
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(reg3)

# Predict mpg
pred1 = predict(reg1, newdata=test)
pred2 = predict(reg2, newdata=test)
pred3 = predict(reg3, newdata=test)

# See how well our model fits
mae(test$mpg, pred1)
mae(test$mpg, pred2)
mae(test$mpg, pred3)
```

Comment: Thank you for the details of the chapters :)

Comment: If you are looking for mathematical insights, I recommend book [Elements of statistical learning](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/ElemStatLearn/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to predict an integer/float, you would need Regression models and if you want to separate into categories you would need Classification models.

Since you need to predict price go for Regression models. There are many Machine Learning models like Linear Regression, KNNRegressor, Decision Trees, Random Forests, Gradient Boosting models and much more.

Now you can create these models in either R language or Python. (I would suggest Python as it is more widely used and has much more libraries than R but its up to you).

After selecting the language of your choice, you can do a course on Machine Learning (depends if you are familiar with ML or not).

Then start with a simple model (Linear Regression) and then build your way up to the more complex ones like Random Forest and Gradient Boosting.

As far as software is considered, you just need an IDE (Integrated Development Environment) where you will type the code and execute it.

**Do let me know if you have further doubts!**